# How can I avoid exposing ASHX handlers to abuse?

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, security, ssl

I have created a JavaScript application.  It talks to an ASHX handler.  The connection is secured with a valid SSL certificate.

When the user clicks "submit", I build a JSON object which represents their answers to some questions.

The JS code sends the object to the handler as a parameter on the URL, so that it can be processed.

If I turn on Fiddler and watch these requests, I can plainly see the JSON object and the URL it's going to.

This application is intended for individual people to create one-off data points.  As-is, it would be trivial for someone to write a script to create 1000s of rows in our database using this publicly available handler.

I have looked into "how to secure JSON data" and the answer always seems to be "use SSL".  But I **am** using SSL, and I can still see the data go across the wire.

I can manually create data by just slapping a properly formed URL in my browser bar and pressing "enter".

Can I prevent users from seeing the handler url and the format of the data it accepts?  The data itself is not secret, but I don't want it to be easy to reverse-engineer the API call that writes to the database.

A generic version of my "on submit" function is below, for reference.

```
function createGenericThing() {
    document.getElementById('btnDoSomething').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('btnDoSomething').value = "Working...";
    var evt = GetJSONObjectFromUserInput();  //returns a valid JSON string
    //expected format: /MyHandler.ashx?command=dosomething&data={json string}
    var handlerurl = getHandlerURL("MyHandler.ashx");
    //grab the parameters they have entered in the user interface
    var params = "cmd=dosomething&data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(evt));

    //set up our request object
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        window.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        window.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    //set up to catch the result after the server replies
    window.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (window.xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && window.xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            //this code will happen after we get a reply.
            //the value in "context.Response.Write()" will come back as .responseText
            if (-1 < window.xmlhttp.responseText.indexOf("Error") || -1 < window.xmlhttp.responseText.indexOf("error")) {
                //if the call returned an error, show it to the user
                document.getElementById('lblError').innerHTML = "An error occurred.  The error was: " + window.xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById('btnDoSomething').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('btnDoSomething').value = "Do something";
            } else {
                //if we get here, then the action completed.
                //navigate wherever we are configured to go (a URL which is in a hidden field), with a param indicating success.
                //it is up to the navigate-to-page to actually pay attention to that parameter and do anything about it (i.e,. show a confirmation message)
                var navigateto = document.getElementById('hfNavigateAfterURL').value;
                navigateto = navigateto + "?datasaved=" + window.xmlhttp.responseText;
                window.location.href = navigateto;
            }
        }
    }

    //get the results from our handler.  this line actually causes SQL to execute on the server.
    //if you watch in Fiddler, you'll see something like:
    //https://someserver/someurl.ashx?cmd=dosomething&data={properly formed JSON}
    //that's the problem.
    window.xmlhttp.open("GET", handlerurl + "?" + params, true);
    window.xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to distinguish between your own request and a request from a malicious user who can read your client code.  You need server-side validation.

Comment: i don't know .net or id provide an example, but consider how a captcha works.. generate some random string on the server side and keep it some kind or session and make json post it back to the server with each request. if the "key' is invalid or was generated longer than x seconds ago then disregar the request.

Comment: @SLaks I know that.  I'm not trying to distinguish between my requests and requests from others.  I'm trying to hide my own request so that it is not trivial to reverse-engineer it.

Comment: `It would be trivial for someone to write a script to create 1000s of rows in our database using this publicly available handler.`  What's wrong with that? How is that different from a normal use? Until you can answer those questions, you're stuck.

Comment: Your users are either allowed to perform actions or they're not.  Can't have it both ways.  If you want to prevent users from doing something, your server-side code should check if that "something" is happening (too many requests in a given time frame, captcha check fails, etc.) and deny the request.

Comment: @David: users are allowed.  And if someone for some reason had a legitimate reason to create a thousand rows through the user interface, that would be fine.  My question is: how do I encrypt the data going across the wire so that my json object is not transparent to users?  In another context, suppose I was submitting a financial transaction and it was {[account-number:123,dollar-amount:500]}.  Is that fundamentally impossible to conceal from the user of the browser?

Comment: @JosephStyons: If the value is *coming from the user* then what good would encrypting it do?  Encryption across the transport layer (SSL) is to prevent 3rd parties from examining the data.  But hiding from a user the data *that the user provided* doesn't seem like it would accomplish anything.

Comment: @David right you are, the data is not a secret.  I just want to encrypt the GET request so the **format** of the data is secret.  In other words, I want to make it difficult to **automate** the calling of my ASHX handler.

Comment: @JosephStyons: Yes.  You cannot send a request (or, in fact, do anything) on a computer without letting that computer see what you're doing.

Comment: @SLaks I am aware that 1) the user can see the data.  and 2) the user can see the traffic and that 3) the user can view source and see the JS.  I want to conceal the format of the data so that it isn't trivial to just grab a string from Fiddler, modify the parameters, paste it in the URL, and have random data go into  my database.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=encrypt+in+javascript+decrypt+in+.net

Comment: @JosephStyons: You could manually encrypt the data client-side, stuff it into a single field, and decrypt that field server-side.  But the client-side code which performs the encryption would also be visible to the user.  The user can debug the client-side code just like the developer can.  What it sounds like you're trying to do is fundamentally not going to work.  You can make it *slightly more difficult* by obfuscating the code (which would also make your own debugging more difficult as a consequence), but you can't prevent it.

Comment: @David I had considered encrypting, perhaps adding a timestamp so the encryption key times out after a while.  But what I'm confused about is why this traffic is visible in plain text to a tool like Fiddler when the traffic is across an SSL connection.

Comment: And @David I am aware that any client-side encryption is inherently security-by-obscurity at best.  A determined attacker could reverse engineer that if they really wanted to.  That's probably adequate in our case (this isn't financial data or anything) but I'm not really satisfied with it.

Comment: @JosephStyons: Again, because you can't defend against the local computer.  SSL encrypts data in transit; Fiddler has an option to decrypt SSL using an MITM cert.  (and browser dev tools run before the SSL happens)

Comment: @SLaks I use the MITM cert for my local development, but in this case I've deployed to a remote server with a "real" ssl certificate.  So the data that I can see is "in transit".  Maybe I'm missing something basic about SSL?  If I'm connected securely to a site, and I do an HTTPS GET request to that site, is my request supposed to be visible in plain text?  That doesn't seem right, but I'll make no claim to be a security expert.

Comment: @SLaks or perhaps you are saying a third-party would not be able to view the traffic, but the end user can, because they can catch it before it is encrypted...  That makes a little more sense.  But now I'm talking to myself.

Comment: @SLaks to put it another way, suppose I'm connected securely to my bank's site. They clearly have ajax-y things happening all over the place.  If I click "send a message" and type a message that says "Hey guys wheres my money", I'm definitely **not** seeing {[message:"hey guys wheres my money"]} going across the wire unencrypted.  So what are they doing, that I'm not?

Comment: @PootieTang I implemented a version of what you suggested.  I just create a new guid and stuff it into a hidden field, and also into Session.  The guid gets attached to the GET request, and the handler just checks to see if that guid is also in session.  So the guid will only be a valid 'key' for as long as session sticks around, and that's good enough for the purposes I have here.  If you post your suggestion as an actual answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks for a reply that didn't assume I was an idiot (although we can't rule that out, either :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I worked out for this.

Keep in mind that the user data itself is not secret.

I only wish to prevent malicious users from monitoring the posting of that data and posting maliciously to my handler.

**Page Load:**

1 - On page load, the server generates two things: A guid, and an encrypted timestamp.*

2 - The guid is stored in ASP.NET session.  Both values are passed down to a hidden field in the client.

Here is the relevant Page_Load code:

```
'give this session a guid.  also encrypt a timestamp.
'when they submit their data, the HTTP request will include both pieces of data.
'we'll verify that the guid actually exists in session.
'we'll also decrypt the timestamp and decide whether they timed out or not.
'this is to mitigate the risk of malicious users posting invalid data to our ASHX handler.
'all of the verification and checking happens in the handler
Dim epochTime = (Date.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds.ToString() '# of seconds since the epoch, to avoid time zone issues
Dim sessionGuid = Guid.NewGuid()
hfAuth.Value = sessionGuid.ToString() + EncryptionHelper.Encrypt(epochTime).ToString()
Session.Add("EVENTKEY", sessionGuid.ToString())
```

**Markup**

Just a new HiddenField, to allow the assignment shown above.

**JavaScript**

The JS gets just one change:  When I do the GET request, I attach the combination of the guid and the encrypted timestamp along with the rest of the request to the handler.

With the original code from the question as a base, I just added this line:

```
params = params + "&guidkey=" + document.getElementById('hfAuth').value;
```

**Handler**

The handler now has the job of validating the key that comes along with the GET request.  This is straightforward based on what we know about the incoming token.

```
...in the ProcessRequest method...
Dim authenticationKey = context.Request.Params(2).ToString()
If IsKeyValid(authenticationKey, context) Then
    context.Response.Write(CreateCRMEvent(eventJSON))
Else
    'if the caller didn't know the key we expected, then just quietly fail
    'by returning a guid.  no need to let malicious users know they failed.
    context.Response.Write(Guid.NewGuid())
End If

...and a new method...
Private Shared Function IsKeyValid(keyToAuthenticate As String, context As HttpContext) As Boolean
    Try
        'a key is valid if:
        '1: it begins with a guid that we have in session
        '2: it contains a timestamp that has been encrypted with our key, and is within the timeout period
        Dim sessionGuid = String.Empty
        Dim lengthOfAGuid = Guid.Empty.ToString.Length '36
        If context.Session("EVENTKEY") IsNot Nothing Then
            sessionGuid = context.Session("EVENTKEY").ToString().ToUpper()
        End If

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyToAuthenticate) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionGuid) Then
            Return False 'invalid because they provided no key, or we have no knowledge of issuing one
        End If

        If keyToAuthenticate.Length <= lengthOfAGuid Then
            Return False 'invalid because their key does not contain a valid guid + encrypted timestamp
        End If

        Dim expectedGuid = keyToAuthenticate.Substring(0, 36).ToUpper()
        If sessionGuid <> expectedGuid Then
            Return False 'invalid because the guid they gave is not one we remember issuing
        End If

        'they knew the guid we have in session.  Check the timestamp.
        Dim iEpochSeconds = 0.0
        Try
            Dim encryptedTimeStamp = keyToAuthenticate.Substring(lengthOfAGuid, keyToAuthenticate.Length - lengthOfAGuid)
            Dim decryptedTimeStamp = EncryptionHelper.Decrypt(encryptedTimeStamp)
            If Not Double.TryParse(decryptedTimeStamp, iEpochSeconds) Then
                Return False 'invalid because the timestamp decrypted, but not to a valid # of seconds
            End If
        Catch
            Return False 'invalid because whatever timestamp they tried to give us doesn't decrypt
        End Try

        'give them 30 minutes to finish.  we can tweak this later if it'keyToAuthenticate a problem.
        Const timeoutSeconds = 1800.0
        Dim maxAllowedEpochTime = (Date.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds + timeoutSeconds
        If iEpochSeconds > maxAllowedEpochTime Then
            Return False 'invalid because their timestamp expired
        End If

        'couldn't find anything wrong.  let it through.
        Return True
    Catch
        Return False 'invalid because the request was in a format we do not recognize.
    End Try
End Function
```

*The encryption is done with [this class](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e5BvcR) (except the key is different of course)

The timestamp is the # of seconds since the beginning of the UNIX epoch.  I chose this to avoid time-zone issues.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like what I've done here is a really crappy version of JSON Web Tokens, which I'll be trying soon. https://float-middle.com/json-web-tokens-jwt-vs-sessions/